# How to set JS object as data object from VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set the data object with an object I'm using in my javascript code.

```
<div class="col-12" id="profile">
    <span>Name: @{{ name }}</span>
</div>

var userProfile = new Vue({
       el: '#profile',
       data: {
          name: user.name,
       }
    }
);
```

Somewhere else in my code:

```
user = {
   name: 'name'
};
```

I tried to use assign function, to set data. Doesn't work.

Anyone can give me a hint?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: this.user = { name: 'name' } or this.$set(this.user, 'name', 'name') or this.user.name = 'name'

Comment: @palaѕн While setting up fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/3sjk4c17/4/) I found my issue. Jquery was causing it due the delay of loading.

Comment: Cool. That's why creating demos helps so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works. Use the methods `setName` and `setSurname` to change the related fields. Be aware that when you update the fields in Vue's `data` the changes don't get reflected in the `user` object, which is outside the scope of Vue.

```html
<!-- Your other code here... -->

<div id="#profile">
   <span>Name: {{ name }}</span>
   <span>Surname: {{ surname }}</span>
</div>

<script>
const user = {
   name: 'Jhon',
   surname: 'Doe'
};

new Vue({
   data () {
      return {
         name: user.name,
         surname: user.surname
      }
   },
   methods:  {
      setName (value) { this.name = value; },
      setSurname (value) { this.surname = value; }
   },
   el: '#profile'
);
</script>
```